# Using ListView with scrollDirection set to Axis.horizontal inside a SimpleDialog throws an error

Tags: flutter, dart

When i try to use a ListView which contains checkboxes with scrollDirection set to Axis.horizontal inside a SimpleDialog throws an error: RenderShrinkWrappingViewport does not support returning intrinsic dimensions. I tried wrapping the ListView with Containers, Flexible.. but it still thorws an error.

If i set the scrollDirection to Axis.vertical it works fine. I am guessing the problem is with it being inside a dialog.

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => SimpleDialog(
          backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 229, 233, 240),
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: ListView(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                children: [
                  ...personCheckboxes.map(buildCheckboxes).toList(),
                ],
              ),
            ),
```

The buildCheckboxes function:

```
  Widget buildCheckboxes(CheckBoxState checkbox) => CheckboxListTile(
        controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
        activeColor: Colors.blue,
        value: checkbox.checked,
        title: Text(checkbox.title, style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 12)),
        onChanged: (value) => setState(() {
          checkbox.checked = value!;
          if (checkbox.value == 'M') {
            maleChecked = checkbox.checked;
          } else if (checkbox.value == 'F') {
            femaleChecked = checkbox.checked;
          }
          checkResults();

          setState(() {});
          //runFilterCheckbox(checkbox.value, value);
        }),
      );
```

I have tried wrapping the ListView widget with different widgets (Container). It still produces an error.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) => SimpleDialog(
          backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 229, 233, 240),
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 100.0,
              width: 100.0,
              child: ListView(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                children: [
                  ...personCheckboxes.map(buildCheckboxes).toList(),
                ],
              ),
            ),
```

Even after wrapping the listView with SizedBox, the problem persist:

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => SimpleDialog(
          backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 229, 233, 240),
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 20.0,
              width: double.maxFinite,
              child: ListView(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                children: [
                  ...personCheckboxes.map(buildCheckboxes).toList(),
                ],
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: `SimpleDialog` on showDialog content ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On horizontal list and `CheckboxListTile` are trying to get infinite width. You can wrap the `CheckboxListTile` with SizedBox widget and provide width. You can take help of `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width`. And for the `ListView` It also required height and width on case and can be used SizedBox with height and width.

```dart
SizedBox(
  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*.5,
  width: 200, //or 
  child: ListView(
```

```dart
buildCheckboxes(...)=> SizedBox(
      width: 200,
      child: CheckboxListTile(
          controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
```

Also you can follow other widget like AlertDialog. or just

```dart
showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) => SizedBox(
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .5,
    width: 200, //or
    child: Material(..
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your Listview in a Sizedbox and give it some height to it and add width as `width: double.maxFinite,`. It should work after you add width as AlertDialog uses an IntrinsicWidth widget that does not allow ListView.builder.

Use Alert Dialog instead of using SimpleDialog. Check below code for alertdialog implementation:

```
showDialog(
   context: context,
   builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return AlertDialog(
         content: Container(
            width: double.maxFinite,
            child: ListView(
               children: <Widget>[]
            ),
         ),
      );
   }
);
```

Comment: Tried it, it still produces the same error.

Comment: Edited the answer check again.

Comment: Still not working. I included your answer in the question.

Comment: change SimpleDialog to AlertDialog. Check answer for implementation.

Comment: still not working, changed to alertdialog. But i would still like to keep SimpleDialog, it scales things better and doens't overflow.